# Detecting Windows System sounds with Python

Tags: python, audio

I have a python script that pulls the cell values from a spreadsheet and inputs it into a program. Problem is that if there is an error that occurs when the information is being input (duplicate value, navigational error, sql error, etc) the script will not recognize that there is an error and just keep running. I'd like to find a way to have the script recognize when these errors occur and hold the script or take another action.

All of the errors vary between each other, but all of them produce a prompt window specifying the error code, the description, and they it plays the default "Windows Background.wav" sound in C:\Windows\media when it. The only thing that remains consistent through all possible errors is that sound so I thought I could have Python store that sound as a variable and constantly check to see if it has been triggered.

I saw modules like pyaudio, audioread, and winsound, but none of them seemed to have any way to read the wav file, store it as a variable, and then monitor the output of the system sounds on the volume mixer to check for it. Hoping there is a solution for this or possibly another way of going about checking for any errors that might occur with the program the script interacts with.

Comment: Usually if you use a good library, you will never have Windows System sounds, but simply exceptions you can catch.

Comment: I'm using pyautogui for a couple mouse clicks into the program and from what I could tell it doesn't have any way to handle those exceptions created by the program it's interacting with. Others might occur from the keyboard module I'm using to write the cell values.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit1**
If you do need to play native windows sound, you can use `winsound` module.
More details on module and available tones [here.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/winsound.html)

Install `winsound` as:

```
pip install winsound.
```

Then go through try-except block when you read from spreadsheet.

Same example as below with `winsound`

```
import winsound

try:
    data = int(raw_input("Enter a number:" ))
except ValueError:
    print "Data type mismatch"
    winsound.PlaySound("*", winsound.SND_ALIAS)
```

**Edit**
You may want wrap data read from spreadsheet in a try , except block and upon error (based on type of data you are expecting) you can use `pydub` to play the audio.

You can use other modules also, but playing audio in `pydub` is one liner.
More details on [pydub is over here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub).

Install pydub as:

```
pip install pydub
```

Here is a little experiment that plays audio (beep) when the input value is not an integer.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

audio_file = "alert.wav"
sound = AudioSegment.from_wav(audio_file)

try:
    data = int(raw_input("Enter a number:" ))
except ValueError:
    print "Data type mismatch"
    play(sound)
```

This will play "alert.wav" (which is basically a 10k sine_wave (beep) file),  if anything other than an integer is entered.

**Output**

```
>>> 
Enter a number:5
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Enter a number:number
Data type mismatch
>>>
```